# Tense of "won't know something until do something"

Tags: tense

I read this,

> We won’t know if it’s a true antidote until they’**ve had** a chance to
>   study it.

But I find other examples are more tend to present tense,

> You won't know until you try.

Why?

Comment: Both of those sentences use exactly the same tense for the phrase: *won't know*. Also, *won't* (or *will not*) is future tense, not present tense.

Comment: @JasonBassford Apparently, they mean the *until* part: the present perfect of *they've had* vs the present simple of *you try*. As far as I know, the present perfect simply puts the clause in the past relative to the future of the main clause. You might call it "past-in-the-future." The present simple puts the clause in the same future as the main clause.